# Como puedo restar valores de un array a otro array?

Tags: javascript, html, array

Ejemplo:
tengo un array llamado caja y quiero que el segundo array le reste a los valores de caja.

primer valor es digamos valor y el segundo es cantidad.

```
    caja[0] = [50,3];
    caja[1] = [20,2];
    caja[2] = [10,1];
```

y el segundo array le resta la cantidad, el valor al no tener cantidad o su cantidad es 0 el valor igual.

segundo array es :

```
    bolsa[0] = [1];
    bolsa[1] = [2];
    bolsa[2] = [1];
```

y que el resultado de como por ejemplo:

```
    caja[0] = [50,2];
    caja[1] = [0];
    caja[2] = [0];
```

ya que bolsa le resto sus valores quedaria algo asi.

Ojala puedan ayudarme.

```
class Billete
 {
    constructor(v, c)
    {
        this.valor = v;
        this.cantidad = c;
        this.imagen = new Image();
        this.imagen.src = imagenes [this.valor]; 
     }
   }

        caja.push( new Billete(50, 10) );
        caja.push( new Billete(20, 2) );
        caja.push( new Billete(10, 2) );
```

Comment: Hola, este problema es fácil solucionar, estas usando forzamente arrays? o podemos usar objetos, otra duda, es en javascript o c#

Comment: Se puede con el signo de restar "-" recorriendo uno de los array y cogiendo el mismo indice para el segundo array.

Answer (score 0):

Lo que pasa es que el valor a restar es dada por el usuario ejemplo caja es mi saldo de los billetes y el usuario decide que cantidad de dinero quiere entonce el usuario va a ver la cantidad de billetes que se le entregara pero primero se entregara desde el mayor en este caso 50 si con solo los de 50 puede darle todo al usuario solo dara los de 50 sino no dara los de siguiente denominacion

osea depende de la cantidad suministrada por el usuario se le restara a la caja siguiendo el mismo orden antes mencionado.